# SQLite or MySQL for a read-mostly website?

Tags: mysql, sqlite, web, scalability

Is it practical to use SQLite as the database backend for a website with, say, 300,000 unique visitors a month ?

Writes to the database will be pretty limited - user signing up or logging in, adding comments etc. The vast majority of the use will just be queries getting content based on a primary key in the URL. I'd like to know if SQLite can cope as a website backend and won't end up dramatically slower then MySQL.

I've seen [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3630/sqlite-vs-mysql) and others, but they're not really the same and seem like they could be out-of-date now too. http://www.sqlite.org/whentouse.html suggests it'd be fine, but they might be a bit biased!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite is a very cool product - and with HTML5 on the horizon, it's a good idea for any web developer to get acquainted with it. However you should bear in mind that sqlite does not scale well. If you ever need to share data across multiple webservers, it's going to be **very** difficult using sqlite as the data-substrate.

However to ease the development, you could look at PDO / dbx_ in PHP which provides an abstraction layer (i.e. same code talks to all sorts of databases) however there are some subtle variations between the way different systems implement stuff like transactions - and variations in SQL - if you do go down this route, I'd recommend maintaining your own abstraction layer between the PHP PDO/DBX calls and your application - think stored procedures implemented in PHP.

> 300,000 unique visitors a month ?

aaaarrrgghhhh! pet hate. While you need to think about how much money your site will be making in order to plan a budget, this is not a useful metric for capacity planning. Really you want to look at expected hit/page rates.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

I think you would be fine. Sqlite is able to support multi-threading just fine, and as you are mostly reading from it, there shouldn't be a problem. Also, if you are writing to it, it fully supports transactions as well. You have to remember though that it's still just one file and no service - so if you are going to cluster it you will be out of luck. Maybe you should check what problems exactly you have with mysql and solve them.

Answer (score 0):

sqlite is very fast, but it becomes difficult to use once you need to cluster. However pretty much all databases are difficult once you need to cluster. If you are read oriented, it shouldn't matter too much which you use. Just make sure you are using memcached.

Comment: -1 : "Just make sure you are using memcached" - why? (the -1 is for making an unsupported assertion - not the fact that the assertion is highly dubious (which it is))

Comment: memcached is a general purpose caching server. If your application uses it then it means you can reduce the load on the database.

Comment: Ok - that justifies your assertion - but your trading off code complexity against a potential gain which is, in my experience, very small - indeed often insignificant (and certainly even worse for a DBMS which implements result set caching like MySQL). Modern OS's spend a lot of time and effort minimising disk access, although sqlite has no shared result set caching, the idea of ensuring transactional integrity and cache consistency in your own PHP code is more than a little odd.

Comment: The difference between MySQL's result set caching and memcached query caching is that MySQL's caching has to happen on the database server. The last thing you want to happen on a server that is difficult to scale is for it to be tied down with processing that could happen elsewhere. Memcached caches are also easy to scale and you can cache more than just query results. Sure, this makes the code more complicated, but this can rectified by integrating it into an abstraction. The gains, far from insignificant, can be huge.